# Http trigger enable Azure function timeout

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Recently I have developed Azure function which act as web hook and http trigger enabled. In this function I am getting JSON payload which contains download URLs.

My concern is in some case download content may have large file(around 200 MB to 300 MB) and as per the Azure documentation, http trigger enable azure function timeout is MAX = 230 secs.

I am already using async/await to download file like below.

```
await fileBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(webClient.OpenRead(downloadItem.DownloadUrl));
```

My questions are below.

1. What are alternate options if my function timeout?
2. Will Azure continue to count seconds while I am downloading file from third party server?
3. In my JSON payload, I have 2-3 download URLs. How can start to download all URL parallel instead of one by one?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a perfect fit for Durable Function - [Fan-out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp

[image]

Your http-triggered Function will start an orchestrator. This will will kick-off n number of activity function. One for each URL.